# How do I push a specific file set to a Git repository without tracking changes?

Tags: git

I have a bunch of files that I want to share with the world. They are scattered over my home directory in various places. They are **not** under version control. I want to take a snapshot of these files and push it to a remote Git repository, so that its HEAD would then refer to the latest snapshot, regardless of what was in the previous snapshot. I do **not** want to `git add`/`rm`/`mv` anything; I want to simply say “here is the new snapshot, make it the new HEAD”.

My idea so far:

1. `rsync` the desired files into `/tmp/snapshot`
2. `git clone --no-checkout` the remote into `/tmp/snapshot/.git`
3. tell Git to commit exactly the current state of the working copy, whatever additions/removals this may imply
4. `git push`

Questions:

- Is there a better / more direct way to accomplish what I want? (a specialized utility perhaps)
- Can I do without `git clone`? (just push the new tree somehow)
- Is `git clone --no-checkout` the appropriate command for step 2?
- How do I do step 3?

Comment: ‘_How do I do step 3?_’ `git add`

Comment: @Biffen Thanks. I had assumed `git add` only added files. Turns out `git add -A` also removes deleted ones.